# Keyboard input (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, keyboard, game-engine

Let's say I'm making a game in Unity and during testing I only have 4 fps. If we have code like the following...

```
if(buttonDown("Spacebar"))
{
   print("Space button detected");
}
```

To my understanding, input would be checked once within the main game loop. This would mean that the user would have to hold the space bar down for at least 0.25 secs every time to insure input detection. I feel like my understanding is off and can't imagine this is how input detection for games actually works. What am I missing?

Comment: 4fps is kind of very low for a playable game unless you are making a game for Sloths.

Comment: yes i realize that 4 fps is terrible, but does that mean it would break input detection?

Comment: It would 0.016 for a 60fps, no game should run at 4 fps. It would not have to be down for that long as it can check the last frame, it would just do that check then and register the input in the next frame. So even if it was 4 fps (constant), the input would be saved and the action would be implemented if the engine deems it necessary in the next frame (0.25 seconds).

Comment: Realistically speaking, Yes. Everything would run at same speed including input.

Comment: Yes, Unity input is polled rather than event driven. (Except for Input.inputString I think, which will let you type a letter to grandma while stopped at a breakpoint)